# Could not retrieve version of JHipster declared by blueprint 'generator-jhipster-vuejs'

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, jhipster

I'm not able to generate a complete project using `jhipster --blueprints vuejs` command.

only the backend created, there is no /webapp directory.

when i run the command, i got this :

```
[![WARNING! Could not retrieve version of JHipster declared by blueprint 'generator-jhipster-vuejs'][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me with jhipster to version 5.3.4 it worked like this:

Try to download the nodejs module with this command:

```
npm i -g generator-jhipster-vuejs
```

and link it to your jhipster folder

```
npm link generator-jhipster-vuejs
```

Now perform the blueprint vuejs with the following option:

```
jhipster -d --blueprint vuejs
```